# jQuery Slideshows on Same Page Move Together on Click

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am creating a jQuery slideshow and I've made the slideshow work well, the only problem is, once I have more than one slideshow on the page, when you click the next button on one of them, the other slideshow moves to the next slide as well and I can't figure out why.

EDIT: A stackoverflow user suggested a fix (thank you) of adding a slideshow ID to each of the slides so that each would have a unique selector. The only issue is the slideshows are being generated in the WordPress loop and I'm not sure of any way to make WordPress assign each one a unique ID...

If anyone could help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated. I've duplicated the issue on this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RsLAA/1/ and here's my code.

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    background-color: #DEDFCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    }

.slideContainer {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }

.slide {
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C9B7B7;
    }

.slideMiddle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

.slideInfo {
    width: 40%;
    height: 80%;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    }

.slideNav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #C9B7B7;
    color:  #DEDFCC;
    }

.prevSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
    }

.slideCount {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

.nextSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    }

.slideCredit {
    width: 40%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

.fix {
    clear: both;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="postContainer">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php $slides = types_child_posts('slideshow'); ?>
    <?php if($slides) { ?>
        <div class="slideshow">
            <?php foreach ($slides as $slide) { ?>

              <?php if (get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-image', true)) {
                  $image = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-image', true);
                  $caption = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-caption', true);
                  $credit = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-credit', true);
                  ?>

                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">


  <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                  <?php echo $caption; ?>
                </p>
                <p class="slideCredit">
                  <?php echo $credit; ?>
                </p>
              </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
              <div class="fix"></div>
            </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
          <?php } ?> <!--end if each if-->
        <?php } ?> <!--end each-->
    </div><!--slideshow end-->
    <div class="slideNav">
        <div class="prevSlide">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="slideCount"></div>
        <div class="nextSlide">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?> <!--end if-->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slideshow").each(function() {
    var slideshow = $(this);
    var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
    var n = 1;

    slideshow.children().hide();

    if(n == 1){
        $(".prevSlide").hide();
    }

    slideshow.children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();

    $( ".slideCount" ).append(  n + "/" + slides );

    $('.nextSlide').click(function (){
        if(n == 1){
            n++;
            $(".prevSlide").show();
            $(".nextSlide").show();
            slideshow.children().hide();
            slideshow.children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            $( ".slideCount" ).empty();
            $( ".slideCount" ).append(  n + "/" + slides );
        }else if(n > 1) {
            n++;
            slideshow.children().hide();
            slideshow.children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            $( ".slideCount" ).empty();
            $( ".slideCount" ).append(  n + "/" + slides );
            if(n == slides){
                $(".prevSlide").show();
                $(".nextSlide").hide();
            }
        }
    });
    $('.prevSlide').click(function (){
        if(n == slides) {
            n--;
            $(".prevSlide").show();
            $(".nextSlide").show();
            slideshow.children().hide();
            slideshow.children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            $( ".slideCount" ).empty();
            $( ".slideCount" ).append(  n + "/" + slides );
        }else if(n > 1) {
            n--;
            slideshow.children().hide();
            slideshow.children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            $( ".slideCount" ).empty();
            $( ".slideCount" ).append(  n + "/" + slides );
            if(n == 1){
                $(".prevSlide").hide();
                $(".nextSlide").show();
            }
        }
    });


  }); // each 1 end

}); // ready method end​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing I found the solution to your problem.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/bZqJ5/1/)
In this way no html tag is renamed or changed, the only thing that changes is the jquery code and a css rule:

```
.slideContainer {
    //this property
    background-color: #DEDFCC;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

For me this is a good sloution jquery code is less and final result seems also the same:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideCount').each(function(){
        var text='1/'+$(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('.slideContainer').length
        $(this).text(text)
        })

    $('.prevSlide,.nextSlide').show()   

    $('div.nextSlide').click(function (){
        var count=parseInt($(this).siblings('.slideCount').text())
        var slideshow=$(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('.slideshow')
        var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
        if(count===slides){count=1}else{count++}
        $(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('div.slideContainer:first').appendTo(slideshow) 
        $(this).siblings('.slideCount').text(count+'/'+slides)
    });

    $('.prevSlide').click(function (){
        var count=parseInt($(this).siblings('.slideCount').text().slice(0,-2))
        var slideshow=$(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('.slideshow')
        var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
        if(count===1){count=slides}else{count--}
        $(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('div.slideContainer:last').prependTo(slideshow) 
        $(this).siblings('.slideCount').text(count+'/'+slides)  
    });
}); // ready method end​​​​​​​​​​​
</script>
```

If you want the Gallery behave exactly like your example (arrows sx dx that disappear when all the images have been browsed).
 Watch this other
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/t534v/)
in this case the css  changes are slightly more, check the css section of fiddle page.
If you like these solution remember to vote me;)
thanks.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I was able to figure out a roundabout solution last night, but it was nowhere near as efficient as yours (took about 30 more lines of code). Thank you so much! This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting such detailed question. From quick view of code I can tell you are using class selector. jQuery needs someway to tell which slideshow's next/previous button was clicked. For that you can enclose the functionality into a function like this

```
function addSlideShow(div_id){

$(div_id+".slideshow").each(function(){
 //rest of your function with embedded div id

});

}
```

addSlideShow('#slideshow1');

For html

```
<div id="slideshow1" class="slideshow">...
```

Comment: Thank you for this fix... the only issue I'm anticipating - and I guess I should have added this to the question - is WordPress. Since the slideshows are being generated in the loop, I wouldn't be able to assign every one an ID... or I just don't know how at the moment. I'll update my question to reflect this...